# Input Function Within While Loop

Tags: python, function, input, while-loop

In this program I am attempting to have it so that the variable integer_enter within the while loop will keep being assigned integers until a 0 is entered in to the input. Every time I run the code I get an EOF error on the "integer_enter= int(input())" line. Why would that be? There is nothing wrong with defining a variable within a while loop so why am I getting that error?

Code for reference:

```
list_num = [ ]
count_even = 0

loop_condition= True

while(loop_condition == True):
    integer_enter= int(input())
    integer_append= list_num.append(integer_enter)
    if(integer_enter % 2 == 0):
        count_even += 1
    elif(integer_enter == 0):
        loop_condition = False 




print('The number of even integers is %d' % count_even)

print(list_num)
```

Comment: The while loop would never stop because `0 % 2 == 0`

Comment: Only if the integer_enter equaled a positive number, right?

Comment: BTW, `integer_append is None` will always be true because `list.append` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your condition for the loop termination. You need to make sure that your `if` is not executed when the `integer_enter` is `0`. [This](http://ideone.com/ELJFei) is a working link to your code.

```
list_num = [ ]
count_even = 0

loop_condition= True

while(loop_condition == True):
    integer_enter= int(input())
    integer_append= list_num.append(integer_enter)
    if(integer_enter % 2 == 0 and integer_enter != 0):
        count_even += 1
    elif(integer_enter == 0):
        loop_condition = False 




print('The number of even integers is %d' % count_even)

print(list_num)
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that 0 % 2 would also equal 0.